# bulk insert into mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a gridview in asp.net page with a checkbox column. I need to insert those checked rows on the gridview, to the mysql table.

One of the most easiest ways would be to find the selected rows and insert them one by one over loop.

However, it is time-consuming considering there may be 10000 rows at any instance of time. Given that this is time-consuming process, there is a risk of losing the connection on the course of insertion.

Is there any way to expedite insertion of huge number of rows?

Thanks,
Balaji G

Comment: google "batch insert"

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the checked records, then write them into to tab delimited or comma delimited format, then using syntax from [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) do the bulk insertion.

Here's the sample format:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```